# How to set block size in PyCrypto AES CTR Mode

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto, ctr-mode

I am trying to get AES encryption to work through the PyCrypto library in Python.

I read in the password from the user and salt from a file.
I then call PBKDF2 to generate a key from the textual password

```
PBKDF2(self.master_password, salt, 32)
```

I then generate an IV using the Random.get_random_bytes

```
IV = Random.get_random_bytes(len(key))
```

I then create a Counter from the Crypto.Util package

```
ctr = Counter.new(32, IV)
```

Then I create an AES object

```
e = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
```

However when I call e to encrypt

```
e.encrypt(user_name)
```

I get the following error

```
CTR counter function returned string not of length 16
```

From the way I understand this error means that the block cipher is 16 bytes which matches with the documentation I found at

https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.AES-module.html

I tried changing it to a 32 byte block size by create the AES object like this

```
AES_Encryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr, block_size=32)
```

but then I get the following error

```
'block_size' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

If someone could point me towards the right direction that'd be great.

Comment: Why do you need a 256-bit block size?

Comment: It was part of the description for my project

Comment: OK, the description is wrong, as Artjom states, there is only one block size for AES, 128-bits. You will need to change the project description. There is no good reasom to use a 256-bit block size and Rijndael with a 256-bit block size has not been as extensivy vetted as AES.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AES is a block cipher with a fixed block size of 128 bit (16 byte). It has three valid key sizes of 128 bit, 192 bit and 256 bit. A nonce for CTR mode, also called IV sometimes, needs to be *at most* as long as the block size which is 16 bytes.

If you want a 256 bit block size, you can't use AES. There are several other algorithms that permit a 256 bit block size such as Rijndael, but there is no implementation of that in pycrypto. AES is a subset of Rijndael.

Usually, we generate a nonce of either 64 bit or 96 bit for CTR mode in order to have some control over how many blocks we can encryption without a counter collision.

```
nonce = Random.get_random_bytes(8)  # 8 bytes
ctr = Counter.new(64, nonce)        # 64 bits remaining
```

or

```
nonce = Random.get_random_bytes(12) # 12 bytes
ctr = Counter.new(32, nonce)        # 32 bits remaining
```

For a 64 bit nonce, you can encrypt at most 2<sup>64</sup> blocks before running into problems. That's more than any data in the world, but the issue is that by choosing the nonce at random, you have a probability of 1 to get a nonce collision after 2<sup>32</sup> encryptions with the same key due to the birthday paradox.
For 96 bit nonces, you can encryption at most 2<sup>32</sup> blocks which is roughly 68 GB of data, but you have a much lower chance of getting a nonce collision.

The nonce is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption. Since you know how long it is supposed to be, you know how much you can slice off.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, definitely made it more clear.